# Xaml - 'Calculated Value' - Can this be done?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following Xaml that is used to bind some data to a chart control:

```
<vf:DataSeries 
  AxisYType="Secondary"  
  RenderAs="Line" 
  DataSource="{Binding CdTeThicknessList}" 
  XValueType="DateTime" 
  MarkerEnabled="False" 
  Color="Navy" 
  LegendText="Beta CdTe - Std. Dev.">
    <vf:DataSeries.DataMappings>
    <vf:DataMapping MemberName="XValue" Path="ReadTime"></vf:DataMapping>
    <vf:DataMapping MemberName="YValue" Path="BetaThicknessStdDev"></vf:DataMapping>
    <vf:DataMapping MemberName="Enabled" Path="PointEnabled"></vf:DataMapping>
    </vf:DataSeries.DataMappings>
</vf:DataSeries>
```

My question has to do with Setting the "Enabled" property. It needs to be set to True or False, based on whether "BetaThicknessStdDev" contains a value (True if it does). "PointEnabled" is not a property of CdTeThicknessList (the datasource), and I'd rather not make it one. Is there a simple way in XAML to set it to true based on whether "BetaThicknessStdDev" contains a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.  Simple, maybe not so much.  Normally, you would use a Converter for this type of thing. [(IValueConverter)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.DATA.IVALUECONVERTER%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true)

Your XAML would look something like this:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding Path=BetaThicknessStdDev, Converter={StaticResource ThicknessToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

Your Converter would look something like this:

```
Public Class ThicknessToVisibilityConverter
   Implements IValueConverter

   Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As System.Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert

      If value is Nothing Then
         Return True
      Else
         Return False
      End If
   End Function

   Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As System.Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack
      Return Nothing
   End Function
End Class
```

You also need to put the following into your Window (or usercontrol):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ThicknessToVisibilityConverter x:Key="ThicknessToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

..where `local` is defined in your xaml as the Namespace of your project that contains the custom converter.

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could bind your Enabled property to BetaThicknessStdDev and use a custom value converter.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) how to do it.